# image uploading in rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I tried image uploading in rhomobile. I choose picture from gallery of mobile and store in my application.
*My question is where the picture is stored after uploading?`*

Answer (score 5):

By default Rhomobile app has sqlite database
 When you upload an image with the help of your model. it store the images name in blob format

```
 enable :sync
 property :image_uri, :blob
```

You can access the image by calling the blog_path of image_uri

```
<% @images.each do |obj| %>
    <img src="<%=Rho::RhoApplication::get_blob_path(obj.image_uri)%>" width='300px' style="padding:10px"></img>
  <% end %>
```